# Where were original Batman and Joker before?

Tags: character, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond-return-of-the-joker

Okay so I was watching *Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker*. And it seems the original Batman and Joker were away somewhere for sometime before returning to Gotham of Terry McGinnis. I didn't get to finish the movie. But I wanted to ask where they were? I don't really know much about the batman beyond universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Batman:**

He was retired and helped Terry McGinnis in his training. It will be full of spoilers how Terry become new Batman but you can watch [Batman Beyond (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond) to know about it.

**Original Joker:**

He was dead as told by original Batman in the film himself and we already know who is the new joker.

<sub>Note: Also remember Batman Beyond is part of [DC animated universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe).</sub>

Comment: Hold up.... Has batman beyond ever met present time batman? Not the old man batman of his time?

Comment: No, he only meet with retired old Bruce Wayne.